# How to encode RGB images into H264 frames (Keyframe + some dependent frames)?

Tags: c#, frames, h.264

So I created images generator (quite simple onewhich generates RGBs) I want to be able to turn some amount of images into H264 KeyFrame+dependent frames (lats say 100) So on each 100 frames generated I need to encode them into H264. How to do such thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple options.  Probably the best available encoder is x264, but it doesn't have a C# interface.  You'd need to define C-style interop calls to use it from a C# program.

Another option would be MSFT's expression encoder SDK, which supports H264.  I'm not sure how much it costs.  Then there's a few other encoder implementations, such as Mainconcept and Dicas, that may have C# interfaces, but those are going to cost you.

One last option is to use DirectShow.NET and [this filter](http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/2009/05/20/monogram-x264-encoder-1050/) to do the encoding with directshow.  You should be able to do everything from C#, and it's through COM interop so the interface is a bit cleaner.

Lastly, almost all encoders work in the YUV colorspace, so you'll likely need something to convert your RGB images--x264 and the Monogram filter both work on YV12.